# OpenGL drawing squares in a for loop

Tags: opengl, colors

I am trying to draw what is in the picture. So I can draw the random colored square but I am having trouble getting the for loop to draw squares in the patter like the image. [image]

Code:

```
for (int i =0; i < image.width; i = i+5) {
    for (int j = 0; j < image.height; j = j+5) {

        //will this for loop give me what's in the image?
        //want to incorporate the code below in here. Modifications?
        glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(i, j, 0);
        glColor3ub( rand()%255, rand()%255, rand()%255 );
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glVertex2i(0,0);
        glVertex2i(1,0);
        glVertex2i(1,1);
        glVertex2i(0,1);
        glEnd();
        glPopMatrix();
    }
}
```

Comment: So, what is it drawing currently?

Comment: well before the i tried to put in the for loop, i had a random colored square being drawn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’re not even using `i` and `j` in your loop body. Try substituting those for `xpos` and `ypos` (whatever those are).

Comment: There (OP) You can see an exhibit of cargo cult programming *sigh*.